# Relation between subspaces and polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

Let $E = \mathbb{R}_{2022}[x]$. If F and G are in E, and $r + s \leq 2020$ where r and s are natural numbers and $$F=\{P(x) \in E: (x-2)^r | P(x)\}$$ and $$G=\{P(x) \in E: (x-22)^s | P(x)\}$$ find:
a)dim$(F\cap G)$
b)dim$(F+G)$ and its basis.

My guess is that F(x) is the polynimials that satisfies P(2) = 0 and G, P(22) = 0. This give us a system in $a_0, a_1, ..., a_{2022}$, the coefficients, and with this two equations I had dim$(F\cap G) = 2021$, but I don't know if I would need to do the r-1 and s-1 derivatives for P(x), so that this will be a lot difficulty to deal with it given r and s are not constants.
For b), by Newton Binomial, I see that F + G is a polynomial of degree 2022 so that his coefficients can be any number, so its dimension is 2023 and their basis are $\{1, x, x^2,..,x^{2022}\}$. Is this solution correct?
Any help will be aprecciated.

Comment: Your characterisation of $F$ is incorrect. If $r = 2$, then $x - 2 \notin F$. However, it is fairly straightforward to explicitly compute the dimensions of $F$ and $G$.

Comment: Are you saying that $(x - 2)^2 \mid x - 2$? This is obviously false.

Comment: Well, I was thinking with r and s we can get r + s equations for the coefficients of P by derivatives of F and G so that $dim(F\cap G) = 2023 - r - s$, that is the number of free variables, but I still don't know a better approach to the second question...